# Matching original siding panels

Tags: wood, siding

My house was built in 1983, and the siding is in great shape.  The problem is that I am changing out a window, and replacing it with a smaller window to work with my kitchen remodel.  The problem is finding siding that will match the original, which I'm sure has been out of production for some time.  Any ideas or custom fabricators that might be able to match for a small job (roughly 10' by 4'?

Comment: What type of siding material?